# What is the correct syntax to specify optional parameters?

Tags: perl, syntax

I have a Perl script that can be called as

```
perl mysrc.pl -a=3 -b=4 -c=6
```

or as

```
perl mysrc.pl -t=15
```

Basically, **(either provide value for `t`) OR (provide values for all of `a`, `b` and `c`)**. Atleast one of the groups of values has to be specified.

How do I say the above in syntax?

```
perl mysrc.pl
     [-a=<value of a>]
     [-b=<value of b>]
     [-c=<value of c>]
     [-t=<value of t>]
```

would mean that all the parameters are optional, which is not exactly the case. What is the correct way to write the syntax for `mysrc.pl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options: either use "|" as an "OR" symbol and non-square brackets for grouping to avoid the "optional" context, or list competing usages on multiple lines

```
perl mysrc.pl {-a=<value of a> -b=<value of b> -c=<value of c>|-t=<value of t>}

perl mysrc.pl UseCaseOneOptions|UseCaseTwoOptions
     UseCaseOneOptions: -a=<value of a> -b=<value of b> -c=<value of c>
     UseCaseTwoOptions: -t=<value of t>
```

For REALLY complicated sets of options (think CVS), do what CVS does (no xterm at the moment, so below is a crude approximation from memory) - that is, the generic "help" message only lists all possible use cases, and to get help about option sets for each use case, you issue a per-use-case help command.

```
$ cvs --help
  Usage: cvs <command> <per-command-options>
  Please type "cvs command --help" to get help on specific command's options
  Commands are: 
      cvs add
      cvs commmit
      cvs remove
      ...

$ cvs checkout --help
  Usage: cvs checkout [-p] [-A] [-m message] [-M message_file] file_path
      -m message:          check-in comment
      -M file:             read check-in comment from this file
      -p:                  non-sticky checkout. Print the file to STDOUT.

$ cvs diff --help
  Usage: cvs diff [-r VER1] [-r VER2] [-w] file_path
       -w:                 Ignore whitespace
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use:

```
mycmd [ -t=tval | -a=aval -b=bval -c=cval ] ...
```

where the '...' represents any other options, or the file names, or nothing at all.  And if one or the other set is mandatory, I might use braces '`{}`' instead of square brackets '`[]`'.  The square brackets usually indicate 'optional'.

Answer (score 1):

You mean just the help text? In that case you can do what Subversion does, for example:

```
$ svn help merge
merge: Apply the differences between two sources to a working copy path.
usage: 1. merge sourceURL1[@N] sourceURL2[@M] [WCPATH]
       2. merge sourceWCPATH1@N sourceWCPATH2@M [WCPATH]
       3. merge [-c M[,N...] | -r N:M ...] SOURCE[@REV] [WCPATH]
```